# How to create project in WebLogic Workshop with support for JPA entity beans?

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, entity-bean

How to create a project in WebLogic Workshop (version 10.3) with support for JPA entity beans?

I am trying create a separate EJB and EJBClient projects in Workshop and EJB3 session beans work just fine, but I am having problems with JPA entity beans.

It seems that when creating a new project you can add support for JPA and BEA Kodo if you are creating a web project, but for some reason you can't add JPA support to a EJB project.

I do want to separate my EJB3/entity bean stuff and Web stuff to separate projects. How can I do that?

Should I just add Kodo/JPA .jar to my EJB project? Or should I make a separate Dynamic webproject and treat that as a EJB project.

Working example projects would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing seems to be to just add the JPA libraries to EJB project and be done with it. It seems that Workshop has no specific support for JPA in EJB projects. Not that it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

http://jaiswaltraining.com/ejb3/weblogic/ch2.php provides some step by step examples of EJB3, Entity Beans with JPA, datasource creation, and everything in Eclipse.